# What's the best architecture for a medium-sized, high traffic web site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, architecture

I'm starting a new project (non-corporative) and I want to know how would be a great architecture nowadays.

What I'm planning for now is to use:

- ASP.NET MVC 4.0
- SQL Server 2008 or 2012
- EF 5.0 under .NET 4.5, with Dapper
- Implementation of Repository pattern (this one http://code.google.com/p/ef4prs/)
- DI with [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)
- Automapper
- WCF Service Layer (for future mobile implementation)

Checking the flow (correct me if something is wrong): **Controller** calls **ApplicationService**, that calls a **BusinessLayer**, that calls **DAL** with UnitWork/Repository, that execute queries over **EF** or **Dapper** (is it correct to query Dapper from a specific method at Repository?), then the result is automatically mapped to a **DTO** and returned to **Controller**, that copy what's needed to a **ViewModel** and returns a View.

The problem here is performance, as I said, the site is planned to have high traffic.
In this case, any of the items listed above could reduce performance? Or this combination leaks something more?
Should I discard the EF, and use just Dapper?
I'm afraid the service layer could reduce the performance because of the traffic.

And finally, I don't know if this architecture is unnecessary, or just poor.

That's a lot of questions, but the focus is to know a great and not "over architected" solution for a medium-sized web site.

Sorry for the English

Comment: You need to be more specific on "high traffic."  tens/hundreds of thousands, millions, tens of millions, etc views/day?  What kind of hardware/cloud resources would be hosting this?

Comment: Seems more like a http://serverfault.com kind of question. Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

Comment: @BrunoVieira He's asking about what software stack would be appropriate, this is likely a better home for it than serverfault.

Comment: "Best" is going to be a matter of opinion, perhaps reword your question to focus on the performance impact of each of those technologies

Comment: @R0MANARMY, what matters now is the software being ready for hundreds of thousands views/day. The hardware is not my business, and would be changed under demand later (cloud maybe).

Comment: @EdmundYeung99, that's exactly what I'm looking for, the performance impact of the technologies I'm using, and what could be better

Comment: Well, [here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35193/Web-2-0-AJAX-Portal-using-jQuery-ASP-NET-3-5-Silve) an example of an ASP.NET project that (at least theoretically) scales to 4+ million pages/day.  Most software today will scale just fine.  It'll be up to you to implement things efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is fairly subjective as there are many possible configurations that can all work well. I can give you some recommendations though.

Mixing and matching EF with Dapper can be a bit of a minefield. In theory, you should be able to fetch objects with Dapper and then `Attach` them to the `DbContext` and update them. However, in my experience that often doesn't work. We started out with EF, then slowly moved to Dapper for fast querying and I figured we could continue to use EF for updates/inserts but I ended up rolling my own insert/update tracking (surprisingly easy) and thus we're slowly phasing out use of EF.

In hindsight, I would suggest picking one and sticking with it. EF should be pretty fast under .NET 4.5. Not as fast as Dapper though, so the pure Dapper route isn't a bad one to take.

Other technologies you could consider:

- ServiceStack (webservice) http://www.servicestack.net/. Highly recommended, low configuration, fast and easy to use.
- ASP.NET MVC Web-API (webservice) http://www.asp.net/web-api. I have no experience with it.
- ThisMember (mapper, *disclaimer: my own library*) https://github.com/JulianR/ThisMember/wiki. Quite a lot faster (10-100x) than AutoMapper and easier to use in my opinion.

Comment: Considering the [EF 5.0 improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx) under .NET 4.5, I'll give it a try. Simple and faster [WebService framework](http://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/service-stack-vs-wcf-data-services/) and mapper will be useful too, thanks